# Синонимы к слову франкенштейн?

Tags: синонимы

Пытаюсь подобрать слово к объекту, который включает в себя функциональность довольно разных объектов. Как если взять велосипед, приделать к нему фен для сушки волос. И в результате получим что-то, что может сушить волосы и на чём можно ездить. Единственное, что приходит в голову - это Франкенштейн, нечто, собранное из разных частей. Но не совсем точно описывает, потому что у него просто были части от разных людей, а тут я хочу сказать, что слеплены функционально разные вещи. Приходит в голову "сборная солянка", но тоже не то. Скорее что-то похожее на эдвард-руки ножницы... Есть нормальное русское слово для описания таких вещей?

Comment: ["Франкенштейн"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD) это всё-таки фамилия создателя "чудовища", а не само ["чудовище"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Чудовище_Франкенштейна).

Comment: для биологических вещей - химера. 
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Химера_(биология)

для технических - комбайн, 
комбинация (это скорее общее - о комбинации чего-либо)...

Comment: tum, народ назвал его по "папе" :>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В последнее время в русском языке активно используется слово «гибрид» в переносном смысле.

> **гибрид** м.
> 1) Организм растения или животного, полученный в результате
> гибридизации.
> **2) перен. Что-л. совмещающее признаки различных
> предметов, явлений.**
>
> [Толковый словарь Ефремовой Т. Ф.]

Также используется префиксоид «мульти-».

> **мульти...**
>  Начальная часть сложных слов, вносящая значение: **указывающий на множественность предметов** или многократность каких-л. — обычно однородных — действий, функций и т. п.
> (мультивибратор, мультиплан, мультиплеты и т. п.).
>
> [Толковый словарь Ефремовой Т. Ф.]

Например, мультиварка (совмещение разных способов приготовления пищи в одном устройстве), [мультитул](https://www.google.com/search?sa=X&source=univ&tbm=isch&q=%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BB%20%D0%A8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F&ved=2ahUKEwi37MS4psXyAhWzSfEDHW14AvwQ7Al6BAgIEEc&biw=1366&bih=657) (совмещение разных инструментов в одном).

Comment: *Eagle*, я позволила себе добавить ссылку в Ваш ответ. Надеюсь, Вы не против.

Comment: @Римма Михайлова Хорошо. Я не против.

Comment: Гибрид наверное самое точное описание того, что я хотел сказать.

Comment: @John Smith Рад, что смог помочь.

Answer (score 1):

Нормальное русское слово для описания таких вещей вряд ли существует (в конце концов, «Франкенштейн» — тоже не русское слово), а из иностранных слов, мне кажется, хорошо подошло бы «монстр». Или «химера».

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня в воображении слово "химера" больше связывается со значением "Неосуществимая, несбыточная и странная мечта".

Comment: Такое значение появилось только в эпоху Возрождения, а в античной древности Химера — это был вот такой жуткий зверь. Для полного, так сказать, счастья считалось, что Химера, кроме того, огнедышаща и бессмертна.

Answer (score 1):

Ещё есть выражение "швейцарский нож", которое означает возможность справиться с любой проблемой в данной области благодаря своему обширному функционалу:
[image]